# NMAKE/ CMAKE Fatal Error cmake_check_build_system Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: windows, cmake, nmake, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to get the ARM GNU Toolchain for embedded development on the RaspberryPi Pico (RP2040) on Windows 10 installed. After successfully configuring the build folder with `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles"`, `nmake -d` is giving me this error:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.34.31933.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

                                cmake_check_build_system target does not exist
                              all target does not exist
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Program' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

This is the part in the Makefile that's throwing the issue:

```
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start C:\pico\pico-examples\build\CMakeFiles C:\pico\pico-examples\build\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 /nologo -$(MAKEFLAGS) all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start C:\pico\pico-examples\build\CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all
```

To me it looks like the space in the path which should be "C:\Program Files(x86)..." is causing the command to abort. Unfortunately I have very little knowledge about makefiles/cmakelists/etc and of what I should edit to make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to install the SDK to somewhere else?

Comment: @Tommylee2k Are you referring to the Windows 10 SDK or the Pico SDK?

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**
It turned out that I have MinGW installed and the `make` location registered as an environment variable in `PATH`. After uninstalling MinGW it works just fine.